# JSON.parse получаю ошибку Unexpected token o in JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Пытаюсь вернуть через REST API данные в JSON.

Node JS + Express Js

server.js

```
var userController = require('./UserController');
app.route('/api/users')
  .get(userController.getUsers);
```

UserController.js

```
var userModel = require('./User');
function getUsers() {
  return JSON.parse(userModel);
}
```

User.js

```
var users = [];
users.push({id: "1", username: "regular", password: "user", role: "1"});
users.push({id: "2", username: "premium", password: "user", role: "2"});
```

Ошибка

```
undefined:1
[object Object],[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Знаю, что там внутри объекты, но как в таком случае вернуть клиенту JSON?

Comment: Разве `[object Object],[object Object]` - `JSON`?

Answer (score 2):

У вас `users` не `json`, а массив. Его уже не нужно парсить:

```
var userModel = require('./User');
function getUsers() {
  return userModel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - проверять приходит ли модель уже в виде JSON. Если да, то возвращать сразу. Если нет, то парсить и возвращать.

```
function getUsers() {
  return typeof userModel === "string" ? 
     JSON.parse(userModel)
     :
     userModel;
}
```

Comment: Комментарий на оба ответа выше. если возвращать return userModel; как есть, то получаю ошибку Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]